# How to detect which item the user clicked in a ListBox win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

What I am struggling doing, is

1. figuring out a wild card for SelectedItems[]

I want a var uploadDir to be based off of the SelectedItem.
the way I currently am going about it I feel is just repetitive code and possible a better way of going about.

[Listbox1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7an7.png)

Also it will not let me set x as null and use that in SelectedItems[x]

### Current Debug Code

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ReportPeriod == "Daily Call Data")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ReportPeriod);
            }else if(ReportPeriod == "Weekly Call Data")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ReportPeriod);
            }
        }
        public string ReportPeriod;
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;
              ReportPeriod = listBox1.SelectedItems[x].ToString();
         }
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

I am working a small program for work, to update our KPI dashboards via excel templates and VLOOKUPS.

So what I have is a user interface that will allow the manager to select the type of data that they will be loading from a ListBox

Ex: Daily Call Data, Daily CSAT Data, Weekly Call Data, etc..

they then browse for the downloaded csv file and press update
the csv is moved and renamed as well as the old file renamed to previous day,month,year etc.

Quick PSEUDO Code

```
int x;
ReportPeriod = listBox1.SelectedItems[x].ToString();

if(ReportPeriod == "Daily Call Data"){
  try{
       string UploadDir = "C:\folder\daily\filename.xls";
       more code...
 }catch(Exception){
    More code...
 }
}
Else If (ReportPeriod == "Weekly Call Data"{
 try{
       string uploadDir = "C:\folder\weekly\filename.xls";
     }
}
```

What I'm needing is to be able to do is either detect which item was selected and assign that to ReportPeriod and create IF and ELSE IF statements from there or if I could possibly assign a value to the Listbox Items (such as a static dir path).

I just don't know how to go about grabbing the selected item from the users mouse click.

Comment: You cannot use an non-initialized variable (x). You should assign a value to it before trying to use it to do anything. In your case I think you need to read the SelectedIndex property

Comment: @steve setting x to the value of SelectedIndex will almost certainly cause an IndexOutOfBoundsException. This code is over complicated. One does not hook the index changed event then keep a variable relating to which text of which index is selected ready to inspect the variable in a button click. We simply ask the listbox at the time we want to know which item is selected, what the SelectedItem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't grab the selected item from the mouse click per se; the list box will tell you which items are selected with the relevant property:

If you only want the user to choose one item from the list, set the SelectionMode to One, then access the SelectedItem property

If you want the user to choose multiple reports and run them all but save them to a common csv, set the selection mode to something that allows multi and then loop through the SelectedItems collection running the report for each

I presume you loaded your list Items collection with strings (text). It's important to note that you'll get them back as object so you'll probably need to cast or .ToString() before you compare with a string to find out what was selected

As for when is a good time in the code to get the value, your button click suits me:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rp= listbox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        if (rp == "Daily Call Data")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("day");
        }else if(rp == "Weekly Call Data")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("week");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe checking if there actuall is a SelectedItem would be a good idea?

Comment: Okay, I will give this a try I am fairly new to c# I am used to PHP so I appreciate all the help.  Now setting the SelectionMode to One , will that keep the array variable at SelectedItems[0] and possible be able to use the .ToString() and just create IF loops for the different string values or would that be to repetitive ?

Comment: @TaW maybe, but where do you stop - implement the entire app? Plenty of advice on NullRef on SO..

Comment: @Joe not sure why you're focused on SelectedItems (plural) - if your listbox is single select then it's intended that you use the SelectedItem (singular) property, though SelectedItems[0] will also work

Comment: I didn't see your update before I posted my comment. Perfect Thank you! Something so simple I was completely overthinking.

Comment: The succinct way, rather than a bunch of IFs, would be to have a custom class that inherits from a base, has an overridden ToString (it shall return the text that is shown in the listbox) and a method (inherited from base) that does the action; then you'd cast your listbox item to that base and call the action; let polymorphism do the correct steps .. but this is a bit much if you're new to c#